# composite run steps action not working under alpine

Tags: github-actions

I followed the steps documented here https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-run-steps-action and created a custom github action sucessfully.

Problem now: it only works if the bash shell is available. Unfortunately the `shell` property is required and it is not possible to use an input variable for that (tested both).

This, doesn't work:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build project

    container: elixir:1.10.4-alpine

    env:
      MIX_ENV: prod

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: My custom composite action
        uses: path/to-my-custom-composite-action@version
```

Error: OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Now I can duplicate the action for alpine (using sh) or build a second version especially for alpine (perhaps autom. via build environment). Is there a better solution?

Comment: Hi, I ran into your post and was wondering: Wasn't it an option to install bash in your container (with `RUN apk update && apk add bash`) to avoid this error?